# Concatenating features of two pooling layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to design a Bi-Directional LSTM model and I want to concatenate features after Max pooling and Average pooling layers.
I have this for my model:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
from keras.layers import Bidirectional
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dropout
from features import train,embedding_matrix,words
from keras.layers import concatenate,AveragePooling1D,GlobalMaxPooling1D

model=Sequential()

model.add(Embedding(words,300,input_length=train.shape[1],weights=[embedding_matrix]))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(20,activation='tanh',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',recurrent_dropout = 0.2, dropout = 0.2,return_sequences=True)))

model.add(concatenate([GlobalMaxPooling1D(),AveragePooling1D()]))

model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

print model.summary()
```

But I am having:
`ValueError: Layer concatenate_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor` which is because I believe the concatenating layer. As I am not adding the pooling in the model.

Can I add two layers in the same model? or Should I define two separate models and then add pooling layers in each of them?

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to use a graph model instead of a sequential model.

Before we get started, I assume

1. your network expects a 2D input tensor of shape `(B=batch_size, N=num_of_words)`, where N is the longest sample length of your training data. (In case you have unequal length samples, you should use `keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences` to achieve equal length samples)
2. your vocabulary size is V (probably is 300 if I understand correctly)
3. your embedding layer encodes each word to a feature of F dimension, i.e. your embedding layer's weight matrix is `VxF`.

   from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Input, Concatenate, Lambda
   from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
   from keras.layers import Bidirectional
   from keras.models import Model
   from keras.layers.core import Dropout
   from keras import backend as BKN

   from keras.layers import concatenate,AveragePooling1D,GlobalMaxPooling1D

   words = Input( shape=(N,))

   f = Embedding(input_dim=V,output_dim=F)( words )
   f = Bidirectional(LSTM(20,activation='tanh',
                          kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                          recurrent_dropout = 0.2, 
                          dropout = 0.2,return_sequences=True))(f)
   gpf = GlobalMaxPooling1D()(f) 
   gpf = Lambda( lambda t : BKN.expand_dims(t, axis=1) )(gpf)
   apf = AveragePooling1D( pool_size=2 )(f)
   pf  = Concatenate(axis=1)([gpf, apf])
   pf  = Dropout(0.2)( pf )
   pred = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(pf) # <-- make sure this is correct

   model = Model( input=words, output=pred )

Finally, I fail to find that keras `Embedding` layer supports syntax like `weights=[embedding_matrix]`.

Comment: will 
`words=Input(shape=(train.shape[1],))`? If yes, then how does this take into account the vocab size? is it implicit when we are passing the `weights`?

Comment: If I do the above then I am getting `TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: I think the problem is that `Embedding(words,300,input_length=train.shape[1],weights=[embedding_matrix])` is problematic, but I did not notice it at the first glance. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Then I am getting `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (198571, 2)` while fitting.

Comment: Also, initially you had `f = Embedding(300,input_length=train.shape[1],weights=[embedding_matrix])( words )` So I am not sure if there is any difference. If I put `Embedding(words,300,input_length=train.shape[1],weights=[embedding_matrix])` then I am getting the error above.

Comment: Did you use a custom Embedding layer?

Comment: No, If I use your earlier version then I was getting, the previous error which was `TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (3 given)`. Right now, I am unable to understand what is going on. Please reformat it. Also, the weights are important. Here https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html they have shown example using ConvNet

Comment: `(198571,2)` is the shape of `Y` as I have used `to_categorical` while fitting

Comment: This is happening because we are passing a 3-D tensor to the Dense layer and while fitting the model like `model.fit(X,Y)` the shape of Y is `(198571,2)` hence, I am getting the error `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (198571, 2)`